# Print the new value of an initialized integer after modifying it inside a void function?

Tags: c++, function, void, cout

I would expect the following C++ code to print 6, but instead it prints 5. How would I change it so that the new value gets printed?

```
#include <iostream>

void increment(int a) {
    a++;
}

int main() {
    int number = 5;
    increment(number);
    std::cout << number; // prints 5, not 6
}
```

Comment: Look up "pass by value" and "pass by reference".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have defined the function means that a *copy* of the `number` variable gets passed to it. Changing the copy inside the function does not affect the original variable.

If you want to refer to the original integer variable inside the function, you need to define the function to take a *reference* to the variable:

```cpp
void increment(int &a) {
    a++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have previously mentionned you should definitely look up pass by value vs pass by reference.

The increment function in your code *copies* your number variable and increments that copy. If you want the original variable to be modified you need to pass it by *reference* by using the & operator.

```
void increment(int &a){...}
```

This will create an alias (a reference) to the variable that you pass and will modify the value at that address in memory (resulting in modifying your original variable).

It is usually not recommanded to pass a primitive type like a int by reference for performance reasons, but as I said previously you should definitely read more about the topic as it's quite fundamental.